# Rails 4: can't save a record to db

Tags: mysql, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, bcrypt-ruby

I've got a problem: i'm trying to add authentication to my first rails app using (mac os x mavericks):
rails 4,
mysql (via mysql2 gem),
ActiveRecord.
Following notes on railstutorial guide I've added:
Gemfile:

```
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password
    attr_accessible :lastname, :firstname, :email, :password
end
```

Create users migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
    create_table :users do |t|
        t.string :lastname
        t.string :firstname
        t.string :email
        t.string :password_digest
    end
end
end
```

Then I'm trying to create and save new user using rails console (because I havent created views and controller):

```
user = User.create(lastname: "LastName", firstname: "Name", email: "mail.mail.com", password: "qwerty")
user.save
```

and there is an error message on my console:

```
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Hope someone could explain me what's wrong and how to get readable error why my transaction was rollbacked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examine `user.errors` in the console, and you'll see that you're missing the required `password_confirmation` attribute (necessary when creating new records using `has_secure_password`)

See the [example in the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password) -- the user doesn't save in that example until the confirmation matches the password.

Comment: Oh, yeah! Definitely I forgot about password confirmation. Thanks!